# unit test fail with NullInjectorError in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs

I have configured the unit testing of the jest framework and also remove jasmine karma (default unit test)

So we need to mock anything or do I missing something in imports?

Bellow I mentions test code

**toolbar.component.spec.ts**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ToolbarComponent } from './toolbar.component';
import { ColorPickerModule } from 'ngx-color-picker';
import { NgxImageZoomModule } from 'ngx-image-zoom';
import { UiSwitchModule } from 'ngx-toggle-switch';
import { SharepointService } from '../../services/sharepoint.service';
import { CommonService } from '../../services/common.service';
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http'
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';

export const BASE_URL = new InjectionToken<string>('BASE_URL');

describe('ToolbarComponent', () => {
  let component: ToolbarComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ToolbarComponent>;
  let sharepointService: SharepointService;
  let commonService: CommonService;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ColorPickerModule,
        NgxImageZoomModule,
        UiSwitchModule,
        HttpClientTestingModule],
      declarations: [ToolbarComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: ToolbarComponent, useValue: "test" },
        SharepointService,
        CommonService,
        HttpClient]
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ToolbarComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();

    sharepointService = TestBed.inject<SharepointService>(SharepointService);
    commonService = TestBed.inject<CommonService>(CommonService);
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });
});
```

It's thrown an error:

```
NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[adalConfig]:
StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[adalConfig]:
NullInjectorError: No provider for adalConfig!
```

[Here I attached the test result screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOxPn.png)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are using adalConfig service in your component then provide it in .specs array

```
  providers: [{ provide: ToolbarComponent, useValue: "test" },
        SharepointService,
        CommonService,
        HttpClient,
        adalConfig
]
```

or if it is module then in the imports:[] array